# How to call API using react js

Tags: reactjs

i am new in react. Can anyone help me that How to call API using react js and show the response in page. I am trying the following code but getting error.

```
export default class UserList extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
            .then(res => {
                const users = res.data;
                this.setState({users});
            })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.users.map(user => <li>{user.name}</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you missed to **declare** the state. you need to declare it in UserList Component. Please follow this example:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class UserList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        users: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
            .then(res => {
                const users = res.data;
                this.setState({users});
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.users.map(user => <li>{user.name}</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```